# usdzconvert Doen't match Material .pngs

Tags: python, safari, arkit, converters

I am having a problem with usdpython tool delivered by Apple.
I'm trying to convert a `file.obj` linked to a `material.mtl` file exported by Cinema4D. Inside `material.mtl` Cinema linked me each material with a specific texture inside the folder `/Faces`

This is my folder structure:

```
/Faces
/file.obj
/material.mtl
```

and this is the command i'm trying to lunch

```
usdzconvert file.obj -v
```

I'm also trying to add material references by `-m` flag but what I get is a 3d object without textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obj files dont have any materials or animation attached to it.Why dont you try converting an fbx file.

I tried the usdz tools for .obj files to change colours and add textures.I added a Green color into the material copied the file and gave command `usdzconvert file.obj -m Green` .The material did not have any effect on the usdz file.I think it is better to apply the texture via commands.

Example:- `usdzconvert vase.obj -m bodyMaterial -diffuseColor body.png -opacity a body.png -metallic r metallicRoughness.png -roughness g metallicRoughness.png -normal normal.png -occlusion ao.png` .

I tried the material part but did not work.If you have texture give them through commands.Refer this link a half an hour [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/602/)